# Change recessed CFL lights to LED

Tags: led

I have the CFL recessed lights in my kitchen but i want to change them to LED, some one at home depot told me that i will need to change the can. Can someone help or guide me to a video or instructions how can i remove the old can with the new one ?

Comment: I have LED lights in all the downlights in my kitchen, and I never replaced the can they're in. Bought 'em at Costco.

Comment: The LED lights at HD or any place like that are usually capable of fitting into any recessed light. Unless you have some unusual lighting thing going on that you have been able to describe to the person at HD, there should be no issue. I have added a few as retro fit in homes.

Comment: Mine are 4 pin CFL so the LED retrofit will not work with them, I will need to change the cans. I know this for sure but what i want to know is how to remove the old can and blast. to change them with the new one

Comment: Keep in mind that LEDs have strict temperature requirements. If there is not enough air circulation, they WILL fail soon (=5k-10l hours) and you'll waste a lot of money (they are expensive to buy). And I anticipate your answer: even if the recess was meant to accept CFL, don't expect it was also PROPERLY sized for them. Often they are not and CFL fail soon (the electronics inside suffers temperature less than LEDs, but still suffers). This applies to CFL. If you have separate ballast, consider only the first half of my comment, the one for LEDs.

Comment: Here's a video on how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAKpSFWuAEc

Answer (score 4):

The question is if the can has a built-in ballast for the florescent light. If the can uses standard screw-in CFL bulbs, then you can just replace the bulb (and probably the trim ring) with a retrofit LED module designed for use in a incandescent can.

On the other hand, if the florescent light has two or four pins to connect into the can, then the can is designed specifically for florescent and includes the ballast for the florescent light. In this case, you will need to replace the can (or modify the can, removing the ballast and rewiring it, which is probably not worth the effort).

Comment: I have 4 pin CFL right now, I do not mind changing them to the LED can but i will like some help knowing how to take the old can out and put in the new one. I did visited one of the home depots and to be honest they were not helpful at all